# Scrolling to input using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an app that I'm working on for a touch screen computer that has a jquery keyboard. My issue is that when they are in a smaller screen the keyboard is covering the input fields and they can't see what they're typing. To solve this I have been trying to user Jquery's scrollto function to make the input show above the keyboard.

However, I seem to be having trouble with it. First of all, it seems that it will only work if a max-height is put on the div I need to scroll inside of. This is an issue because the content is dynamic and I have no idea how big the page can get and I don't want it to get cutt off. Is there a way to have the scrollTo work without setting a height?

Also, It seems I can only get the scrollTo to scroll to the top of the page on not to the actual element. And in some instances it's actually scrolling the content off the page. Is there any way to fix this?

My html kind of looks like this.

```
<div class='container'>
  <input class='title' />
  <input class='date' />
</div>
```

and the jQuery I was trying to use looks something like this

```
 $('.container').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.date').offset().top)
    },500);
```

And a fiddle to help. Please not that yes the classes are different inside the fiddle because I am only using it as an example to play around with.
http://jsfiddle.net/vkut3/5/

Also, I am not looking for a plugin, my company is pretty against plugins. **And I cannot put the scrolling on the html, body because that needs to have an `overflow:hidden;` on it.**

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...it appears that the jQuery's `offset().top` is returning a negative value. As a result, attempting to use `animate()` with a negative `scrollTop` brings the scrolling to the top of the page.

Combining this with the current scroll position of the parent does fix this, however:

```js
$('.bookQuestionBtn').on('click', function(){
    $('.scrollable').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.scrollable').scrollTop() + $('.date').offset().top)
    },500);
});
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkut3/7/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** Looks like the previous answer I had only worked because the input was situated in the middle of the list - changing its position makes a mess of it. I've updated it now.

**EDIT 2:** To get this working without the `max-height` on `.scrollable`, you'll have to change what you're using `animate()` on. The overflow actually gets transferred over to the `<body>` (or `<html>`, depending on browser), so you should animate those instead:

```js
$('.bookQuestionBtn').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('html').scrollTop() + $('.date').offset().top)
    },500);
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vkut3/9/). Work in Chrome 28, though I can't speak for other browsers, so let me know if there are problems.

**EDIT 3:** In light of the new requirement that the `<body>` and `<html>` cannot be scrolled (because they have hidden overflow), try using my original JavaScript solution, but using this CSS:

```css
body, html{
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0;
}
.scrollable{
    overflow-y:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkut3/12/) showing the implementation. Rather than using a `min-height` (since I don't think you want a set height for this), I just stretched `.scrollable` to the height of the viewport. This way, it mimics how the `<body>` would scroll, but works even if the overflow on the `<body>` is hidden.

**EDIT 4:** Okay, hopefully this is it. Since you're using a jQuery keyboard, that means you should be able to access that element and grab its height. Just resize `.scrollable` to fit the remainder of the viewport after it opens, so elements will never end up hidden behind it:

```js
// This should be run after the keyboard opens, preferably attached to a callback
var scrollableHeight = $(window).height() - $(".keys").height();
$(".scrollable").height(scrollableHeight);
```

The above script should be used in conjunction with the original JavaScript suggested for the scrolling functionality. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkut3/20/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you! That's half my issue, but I still kind of need to get rid of the max-height. I can't declare any height on the page I'm working with because of how the elements are coming in.

Comment: No problem! Actually, I fixed my answer just now because it actually only worked in a specific use case. (The new one works just as well, and is actually correct now). Let me look into the `max-height` issue...

Comment: All right, I've posted a new fix so that the `max-height` isn't needed for this to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I can't put a scroll on the html or the body. I'm working on an app that is completely touch screen and part of the requirement is that the overflow on the html and body has to be hidden. That was why I was use the div to do the scrolling.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to reflect these requirements, let me know if they are suitable for your situation.

Comment: :( Even with the height of 100% it doesn't want to work. http://jsfiddle.net/vkut3/13/

Comment: Eh, odd. It seems to work for me, what browser are you looking at it with?

Comment: Windows Chrome and internet exploder.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you scaling down the results pane so it's very, very short (so it can actually scroll enough to see the effect)? I'm using Chrome 28 and Firefox 20.0, and both seem to work reasonably well...

Comment: The thing is though, I really need the page to be big because when it's scrolling the actual page will not be small. It will have a jQuery keyboard on the bottom half of the page that is blocking the fields...that's why it needs to scroll so you can see what's being typed.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just to clarify, you're using a jQuery keyboard, and not the mobile device's native soft keyboard?

Comment: Yes, it is a separate keyboard since it is a touch screen computer not mobile.

Comment: Added one more update. Let me know if it helps you - this one dynamically resizes `.scrollable` so you'll be able to use the original script even with a jQuery keyboard popping up.